# Show Only Grouped Products in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

In Woocommerce, Due to an inventory sku issue with clothing size, we have two different products for ultimately the same product. Let's call it a blue shirt, but it is 2 different products in our store due to an ordering decision. I've created a grouped product to handle the display of this. 
However I can't seem to hide the linked products from my shop. When I use the `WC_Product_query` class and the get_products function, it doesn't seem to return all 46 products that are being queried. I'm wondering what exactly, I'm doing wrong and/or if there is a better solution.

Placed the following in my functions.php child theme:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'only_grouped_products_query' );
function only_grouped_products_query( $q ) {
    $query = new WC_Product_Query(array($q));   

    $products = $query->get_products();

    $linked_array = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($products as $product){     
        $i++;
        /*
        echo $product->get_name() .' - ' . $product->product_type .'<br>';
        $is_grouped = $product->product_type;
        if ( $is_grouped == 'grouped' )
        {
            // echo $product->get_name() .' - ' . $product->product_type;
            $get_child_id = $product->get_children();
            if (is_array($get_child_id)){
                foreach($get_child_id as $child_id){
                    $linked_array[] = $child_id;
                }
            } else {
                $linked_array[] = $get_child_id;
            }
        }
        */
    }
    echo $i;
    // $q->set( 'post__not_in', $linked_array );
}
```

The above code snippet does work, but it doesn't pull in all 46 results that the query is showing when I dump the original $query variable. $i only returns 10 results.

Answer (score 4):

*Your question body explanations are not so clear… So I base this answer on your question title.*

As the product type in Woocommerce is handled by `product_type` custom taxonomy, you need to use a **Tax query** instead.

The following code will display only grouped product types on all Woocommerce archive pages:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'only_grouped_products', 20, 1 );
function only_grouped_products( $tax_query ){
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'product_type',
        'field'     => 'name',
        'terms'     => array('grouped'),
    );
    return $tax_query;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

---

#### Woocommerce default product types *(and other custom product types)*

So you can handle any product type:

- For **Simple** products you will use: `'terms' => array('simple'),`
- For **Variable** products you will use: `'terms' => array('variable'),`
- For **Grouped** products you will use: `'terms' => array('grouped'),`
- For **External** products you will use: `'terms' => array('external'),`

And also all these custom product types (from known 3rd party plugins):

- For **Composite** products you will use: `'terms' => array('composite'),`
- For **Simple Subscriptions** products you will use: `'terms' => array('subscriptions'),`
- For **Variable Subscription** products you will use: `'terms' => array('Variable Subscription'),`
- For **Booking** products you will use: `'terms' => array('booking'),`

> You can **combine multiple product types too** like for example simple and grouped products types only:
> You will use: `'terms' => array('simple', 'grouped'),` … and so on.