How to hide children of grouped product on Woocommerce Loop
So, in WooCommerce, I am trying to hide on the loop, only the children of a grouped product. I have searched all over and only found this partial answer (posted here by Yariel Gordillo Linares) but it also hide the grouped product parent. Can someone update the linked solution so that it does not hide the grouped product parent, but only the children? Other than that, the partial solution linked above works perfect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I thought I was pretty clear. I stated that the solution posted by Yariel Gordillo Linares worked except that it also hid the grouped product parent. What I need is Yariel's solution but updated so that it does NOT hide the grouped product parent, but only hides the children.

I flagged as a duplicate because I think any answer to this post would be equally good as an answer to the other one. You're absolutely welcome to disagree though.

Wow, at first, I did ask this very question in that original post, but was told that I needed to start a new post with this question. Hence, my new post here. But, it seems this community is more interested in being condescending jerks than helping me find a solution. So, since it's clear you don't want to help, I will no longer post here...thanks for nothing.

I didn't mean to come off as condescending, and I'm sorry if I did! I didn't know the context for this post, so I came to an incorrect conclusion. Now that I know what happened, I've retracted the flag. I don't know how to answer your question, but hopefully someone else can.

You can use WC product query - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query#general in the type section you have an example with the type of product. Another example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52594110/show-only-grouped-products-in-woocommerce
